# How to show more option with long text with jquery?

Tags: jquery

When displaying long text content, show substring with continues reading button to show the complete text.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Your question is very unclear in exactly what you're trying to achieve.  Please have a read of the [help] and the [ask] section in particular

Answer (score -1):

Here is the plugin:

```
$.fn.continueReadingText = function(options) { 
var settings = $.extend({
    // These are the defaults.
    charsNum: 100,
    toggleText: "Continue Reading",
}, options );

$(document).on("click",".continue-reading",function(){
    $(this).hide();
    $(this).next('span').show();
});

return $(this).each(function(k,elm){            
    var _str = $(elm).html();
    var _l = $(elm).html().length;
    if(_l > settings.charsNum){
        var last_cut_word = _str.substring(0,settings.charsNum).split(" ").pop();
        if(last_cut_word.length == settings.charsNum){
            lengthBeforeLastWord = settings.charsNum;
            continue_from = settings.charsNum;
        }else{                
            lengthBeforeLastWord = settings.charsNum-last_cut_word.length;
            continue_from = settings.charsNum-last_cut_word.length;
        }


        var short_txt  =_str.substring(0,lengthBeforeLastWord);
        var _toggle = '<a class="continue-reading" href="javascript:;">...'+settings.toggleText+'</a>';
        var _continue_txt = _str.substring(continue_from,_l);
        var _formated = short_txt+_toggle+'<span style="display:none">'+_continue_txt+'</span>';                
        $(elm).html(_formated);
    } 
});
```

};

Here is the element to apply the plugin:

```
<span class="txt">Lorem ipsum, or lipsum as it is sometimes known, is dummy text used in laying out print, graphic or web designs. The passage is attributed to an unknown typesetter in the 15th century who is thought to have scrambled parts of Cicero's De Finibus Bonorum et Malorum for use in a type specimen book.</span>
```

Invoke plugin:

```
$(".msg-span").continueReadingText({
    charsNum: 200,
    toggleText:"Show More"
});
```